# C++ queues of pointers to object c2228 error

Tags: c++, pointers, queue

I am trying to have a queue of objects and modify them for later. Since making a queue just makes a copy after modifying them in the queue and removing them, they disappear. So I need a queue of pointers to my objects to get around this (or so i understand).

My Class:

```
class process { 
    int waittime;
    queue<int> cpuburst, iotime;
   }
```

Then I create my queue like this:

```
process *P1;
process *P2;

P1 = new process(//info to fill my P1 with data);
P2 = new process(//info to fill my P2 with data);

queue<process *> readyque;
queue<process *> onCPU;

readyque.push(P1);
readyque.push(P2);
```

That compiles fine, but when i try to do anything to the queue with the .front() or .push() i get the error `C2228: left of '.cpuburst' must have class/struct/union`
and i get the error `IntelliSense: expression must have class type` for the "onCPU"

on this line:

```
x = onCPU.front().cpuburst.front() + y;
```

I'm just trying to get x to be equal to what ever is in the top of the queue in my class, which is also on top of my onCPU queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `onCPU` contains pointers, when you do `front()` you'll get a pointer out of it. To access a member of an object through a pointer, use `->`:

```
x = onCPU.front()->cpuburst.front() + y;
```

Since you are unsure whether having a `queue` of pointers is a good idea, ask yourself this: should the `process` objects be *part of* the `queue` which has sole ownership of them? Or should the `queue` simply refer to objects created elsewhere?

If you can avoid dynamically allocating objects, that's always a good thing. Perhaps a `std::queue<std::reference_wrapper<process>>` would be useful.

If you want to keep dynamically allocating them, consider a smart pointer (such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`).

If you stick with raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects, don't forget to `delete` them.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I don't know what I did wrong because i swear i tried the -> operator! haha oh well thanks for your help

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but to delete it i simply do `delete P1` ?

Comment: @slowsword Correct. `delete P1; delete P2;`